# How to Display Dates in Calendar View from Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, calendarview

I needed help with this. How do I display dates in Android CalendarView widget?
I have MySQL database with dates, and I can query it with PHP and get JSON data from that. The problem I am having is how do I display these dates in CalendarView? And do I do it so when it is clicked, it takes me to new activity that corresponds to the date that is clicked?

Comment: Convert your database date to milliseconds then use this function .    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setDate%28long%29

Comment: Oh wow thanks man. Now how do I do so that when I click on it, it takes me to a new activity that shows fields from database on that date?

Comment: Also, can I set multiple dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your database date to milliseconds then use this function.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setDate%28long%29

then you can able to added click event by

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                    int dayOfMonth) {

**here you start new activity.**

            }
        });
```

thanks

Comment: I think, you able to added many data by call same function many time.

Comment: Also, how do you think I can do so that I don't need to make the method for many different days? Like how do I use only one?

Comment: Meaning, if the user clicks on any of the days, it takes them to a page, where it is then customized for the date he clicked on

Comment: This is OPP concept. Read about it.

Comment: Ok, very good. How do I do so that when I add an event, it changes the color of that? Can I use CalendarView? Or do I have to use some other class, such as ExtendedCalendarView?